# iOS Page based template, regarding UIPageViewController and UIPageControl color of the dots

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Im having a problem trying to change UIPageControl color of the dots after create a Page based template on xcode and just changing UIPageViewController transition style to Scroll.

The dots aren't appearing on view, i don't know why.

I've just changed that:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

And, on AppDelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Any help, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're on the right track. Using the appearance proxy should work. I do it like this and it works (do it in your AppDelegate, and do it *before* the interface appears):

```
UIPageControl* proxy = 
    [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPageViewController class], nil];
[proxy setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor];
[proxy setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[proxy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

You also *must* implement the two delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc {
    // ...
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc {
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, the UIPageControl will not appear!

Apart from that, I cannot see much difference between what you're doing and what I'm doing, but I know that my code does work. You can download and try it here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thank you! Now It works!
(It was the implementation of presentationCountForPageViewController and presentationIndexForPageViewController)

Comment: Yeah, after I noticed that my appearance code was the same as yours, I figured it was probably the delegate methods. :)

Comment: BTW you have to admit that their default white on white UIPageControl is pretty silly.